# Spring Cloud Config Server allow to access only one profile

Tags: spring, config, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I am attempting to setup a Spring Cloud Config Server to provide the configurations for multiple applications.

We have a repository with all the configurations of our applications in all the environments. So, for example

```
.
├── application-dev.yaml
├── application-preprod.yaml
├── application-prod.yaml
├── application-test.yaml
├── application.yaml
├── application-1
│   ├── application-dev.yaml
│   ├── application-preprod.yaml
│   ├── application-prod.yaml
│   ├── application-test.yaml
│   └── application.yaml
├── application-2
│   ├── application-dev.yaml
│   ├── application-preprod.yaml
│   ├── application-prod.yaml
│   ├── application-test.yaml
│   └── application.yaml
```

Every environment has its specific config server, that takes the data from that repository. I'd like to have a situation in which in every environment I can only access the global files (`application.yaml`, `application-1/application.yaml`, `application-2/application.yaml`) and only the files specific for that environment (so, in dev environment I can't access the `application-prod.yaml` or `application-1/application-prod.yaml` file).

I've tried with this configuration:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: git
  cloud:
    config:
      label: main
      profile: git
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://gitlab.com/organization/empty-configuration-repo.git
          username: deploy-token
          password: secret
          searchPaths: '{application}'
          defaultLabel: main
          repos:
            dev:
              uri: https://gitlab.com/organization/configuration-repo.git
              username: deploy-token
              password: secret
              searchPaths: '{application}'
              pattern: '*/dev
```

But it allows to me to call: `http://localhost:8888/application-1/dev,prod` accessing in this way the prod values. I think this behaviour is caused by this note in the [Spring Cloud docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_pattern_matching_and_multiple_repositories):

> Spring Cloud guesses that a pattern containing a profile that does not end in * implies that you actually want to match a list of profiles starting with this pattern (so */staging is a shortcut for ["*/staging", "*/staging,*"], and so on). This is common where, for instance, you need to run applications in the “development” profile locally but also the “cloud” profile remotely.

Is it possible to achieve this result without separing the repositories? It is useful to have some  properties shared between all the environments.

Comment: It's anti patterns! you can try spring.cloud.config.label=yourBranch to split environtment nonprod and prod